# Need to Delete current password (if Prepopulated) in reset popup window using selenium

Tags: selenium

After clicking reset password link I need to verify whether password (i.e testdemo)is prepopulating in current password text box, if so then I need to clear those values.

[image]

Comment: first i need to check whether it is prepopulating , if it is prepopulating then i need to clear the password value

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: first i need to check whether the login password is pre-populating, if so then i need to clear those content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understood your scenario, you are checking that your password is auto populated in password field and If so then you need to clear that

You can do this - First you need to check is there any value in password field if so then do clear

```
    int passLength = driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).getAttribute("value").length();
    if(passLength>0)
    {
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
     }
```

Comment: glad to hear . If It is helpful please `accept` the answer